# Windows 10 WSL2 expo cannot find simulated android device from Android Studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo, wsl-2

I am new to android development and am trying to learn react-native by following a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-S5a0eXPoc). The problem is **whenever I try to start my react-native project within my simulated android device, expo cli cannot find it**.  This step is at the 25 minute mark of the video and my progress can be summarized as follows:

1. I have react-native on my machine and have installed expo cli
2. I've downloaded Android Studio which is located: C:\Users..\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
3. I have my emulated android device up and running via Virtual Device
   Manager
4. **After typinng "npm start" When I type "a" within the terminal of WSL to run this app on my virtual android device I get the following message when it tries to open the emulator:**

> No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started
> automatically. Please connect a device or create an emulator
> (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator).

At which point my expo developer tools browser window displays that

> Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start
> command to start the CLI again

When I goto the terminal and do this, it just restarts this failure over again when I type "a" to start my app in the simulated android device.  Some of the solutions I've tried are:

- following the documentation on the workflow android studio emulator link.  I find though that all of the options within my version of android studio look drastically different, and that my file location is much different than what they have listed.
- uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio
- Making sure SDK tools is checked as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789556/android-studio-sdk-tools-directory-is-missing) stack overflow post
- following the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145379/how-to-connect-android-studio-running-inside-wsl2-with-connected-devices-or-andr) stack overflow post, however I am not trying to connect a phone via usb so this does not help me.

My setup is as follows:

- OS: Windows 10
- VM: WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Text Editor: Visual Studio Code 1.63.2
- Android Studio: BumbleBee 2021.1.1
- Expo CLI version: 5.0.3

here are some screen shots:
[image: expo cli error]

[image: expo browser tunnel ready]
^ that one is right before I try to type "a" within the expo cli within terminal.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it yet?