# adb devices hangs and after a while times out on WSL2

Tags: android, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Running on Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL2):

```
➜  ~ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.1-8253317
Installed as /home/eliya/dev/Android/platform-tools/adb
```

Running

```
➜  ~ adb devices
adb W 04-28 16:43:11 20145 20145 network.cpp:149] failed to connect to '172.23.160.1:5037': Connection timed out
* cannot start server on remote host
adb: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:172.23.160.1:5037: failed to connect to '172.23.160.1:5037': Connection timed out
```

Running

```
➜  ~ adb start-server
adb W 04-28 16:47:17 21475 21475 network.cpp:149] failed to connect to '172.23.160.1:5037': Connection timed out
* cannot start server on remote host
error: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:172.23.160.1:5037: failed to connect to '172.23.160.1:5037': Connection timed out
```

But when I run it as root, it seems to work fine:

```
➜  ~ sudo adb devices
List of devices attached
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  device
```

How can I make `adb` to work without sudo permissions?

#### Update 1

running `adb -H localhost ...` seems to be ok. What am I missing here?

#### Update 2

Running in Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\coeli> adb start-server
```

and then in WSL2 (hangs for a while and then fails):

```
➜  ~ adb devices
List of devices attached
* cannot start server on remote host
error: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:172.23.160.1:5037: Connection timed out
```

Comment: execute `adb start-server` on Windows host (outside WSL2)

Comment: @Robert it seems to work just fine. After that, when I run `adb devices` inside WSL2, it still hangs, but only outputs "List of devices attached", and the process doesn't exit.

Comment: @Robert It fails afterwards. See my update (2)

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242444/150978?

Comment: Actually yes, but it's not the issue. The issue is that adb in wsl2 fails to connect to the host

Answer (score 3):

If you want WSL to be able to talk with the `adb` server running in Windows, you have to start the server in such a way that it will listen on all interfaces, not just the default one. This is done with `-a`, like so:

```bash
.\adb.exe -a nodaemon server start
```

You can also put a `-P` in there if you want to use something other than the default port of 5037, like this:

```bash
.\adb.exe -a -P 5037 nodaemon server start
```

If you still have problems, double-check your Windows Firewall. However, since this is all local interface stuff, that shouldn't be a factor in most installations.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a fix for this. In my case, the issue was caused by not installing sdkmanager properly. I used openjdk11 instead of openjdk8, which is required by the sdkmanager to run properly. In anycase, following this tutorial https://gist-github-com.translate.goog/georgealan/353a548814fe9b82a3a502926c7a42c6?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp#passo-4%C2%BA
should allow you to get it up and running without needing to use sudo commands. Article is for ReactNative but you dont need to follow the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, check your `ADB_SERVER_SOCKET` environment variable. I had it set to something because of some previous troubleshooting but forgot to clean it up. Removing it from my `.bashrc` fixed the issue.