# How to run Android emulator on windows while using WSL2 with zsh?

Tags: android, linux, react-native, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58229368/13495096

I need to develop using `react-native` in Windows through WSL2.

I did exactly what the answer says and after a few hours of solving some errors, got to the point where:

- WSL2 is installed and running (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
- Android Studio is installed on Windows 10 (Pro x64);
- ADB is with the same version in both WSL2 and Windows (1.0.32);
- $PATH is configured properly (below) in my .zshrc file:

```sh
# Android SDK

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH
```

I start a device on Android Studio (Windows) and in Powershell, when running `adb devices`, it returns:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

When I run `adb devices` on my WSL terminal, it returns only `List of devices attached`, with nothing else.

Based on the linked answer, **it's possible to do it** but I can't. How can I make that happen? What am I missing?

I'm moving from OS X to Windows and I never tried Linux.

Comment: Here is a working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912223/running-wsl2-and-android-studio-at-the-same-time-with-a-ryzen-processor

Comment: In rescent android studio, no need to setup _ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_    
``` lang-sh
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/_<user>_/Android  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```
is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Ended up finding this tutorial that solved my problem (but raised some others, like not being able to access localhost from Android Emulator)

https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade

Answer (score 6):

This question is already resolve in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71414575/4133408), and the solution for this problem is very simple:

for example, my SDK PATH in windows is in this location:

`/mnt/d/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe`

then in my wsl bash console I need to install adb:

`sudo apt install adb`

the default installation PATH in wsl is this:

`/usr/bin/adb`

now change the adb to adb_bk inside the wsl installation PATH:

`sudo mv /usr/bin/adb /usr/bin/adb_bk`

finally change the PATH inside your wsl installation for the windows PATH installation with the adb.exe:

`sudo ln -s /mnt/d/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe /usr/bin/adb`

And when I run my ADB device in my windows this device is attached in my wsl adb:

`adb devices`

Comment: This actually works. I had to use the path ` sudo ln -s /mnt/c/Users/{YOUR-USERNAME}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe /usr/bin/adb`

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward two ports from your Windows (10-11) machine to the WSL-2 - the easiest way is to use `socat`, i.e., in Ubuntu, install it via: `sudo apt install socat`.

Now, in WSL-2 (e.g. Ubuntu command line), kill the adb server (if it is running): `adb kill-server`.

Start you favourite emulator in Android studio in Windows.

You can restart ADB server in Windows (e.g. PowerShell) to make sure it is up-and-running:

```
adb kill-server
adb -a nodaemon server start
```

Forward ADB port 5037 in WSL-2:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5037,reuseaddr,fork TCP:$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f 2):5037
```

And finally forward the emulator port 5556 in WSL-2:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5556,reuseaddr,fork TCP:$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f 2):5556
```

You can use `nohup socat [... the rest of command]` to run the forwarding in the background to avoid having open several terminals.